# List doesn't recognize subcommand transform: Error in Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi3, cross-compiling

i am using [this](http://ulasdikme.com/projects/raspberry/Qt_for_raspberrypi.php) to cross compile with raspberry pi, but i stuck in the step

```
../qt-everywhere-src-6.0.0/configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /opt/qt5pi/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtscript -nomake examples -make libs -pkg-config -no-use-gold-linker -v
```

because it shows the error "List doesn't recognize subcommand transform"
I am using Ubandu 18.04 in virtual box
try to cross compile in Raspberrypi3
My all code is created in QT creator (C++ - qt5 version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- cmake version in ubuntu 18.04 is [3.10](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/cmake)
- [TRANSFORM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html#transform) is new in cmake since 3.12
- [System requirements to build qt6](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_6_from_Git#System_Requirements) : **CMake** (**>= 3.16**, >= 3.18.4 for Ninja Multi-Config, >= 3.21.1 for static Qt builds in Qt 6.2+)

**So, you need at least version 3.16 of cmake**